# Updating timezone on Google Cloud SQL automatically

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm try to deal with the winter and summer time in a Google Cloud SQL instance. What I'm doing now is changing the flag default_time_zone in the configuration every time the time in my region changes. I need it to do it automatically. What I tried already:

1) Looking for a configuration for Time Zone Name to set "Europe/Paris" instead of "+01:00", but Google Cloud doesn't work with this (there's a request for developers of Google to do it but it's not done yet).

2) Changing with a script with "set global @@time_zone='Europe/Paris'" but it raises:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
>   SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

because GCP doesn't allow use super user on mySQL.

Any idea how to bear with this ?

Comment: Have you considered running the server on UTC? Then the front end would be responsible for translating time to local time and you would never have to be up configuring the timezone at 3 a.m. on a Sunday again. [Should servers have their timezone set to GMT/UTC?](https://serverfault.com/q/191331/109573)

Comment: Date/Time should be UTC. it is the job of the Frontend to display date/time in local timezone, not the database.

Comment: Yes, I consider use UTC but all my data now is in +01:00 (or in Summer +02:00). Not only the front-end has to deal with this, as the back-end has to know the timezone depends on another table. I'll figure out how to use UTC and convert all my data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/known-issues#administrative_issues):

> Automatic adjustment to daylight savings time is not supported; you
>   must update the `default_time_zone` flag manually to account for
>   daylight savings time.

So currently, the only approach is to wait for feedback from the Cloud SQL engineering team in the [public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/74600960) regarding the daylight saving time support. There's also [another](https://issuetracker.google.com/78686880) Feature Request open to allow changing this yourself in the MySQL `time_zone` table as per 2), which you might find useful to keep track of by starring it.